# WordPress Customizer Help with FontAwesome Icon

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer

Here's the scenario - I want to select fontawesome icons from the dropdown list but it's not working. For some reason the class inside `span` is not adding up (I have tried `jQuery().append()`, CSS) but so far no luck. ANY help would be appreciated.

**Code in `Page.php` file**

```
<div class="features-block-one">
  <div class="icon-one">
   <span class="<?php get_theme_mod('features_one_icon' ,'fa fa-bullseye');?>">  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code in Customizer file**

```
//block one icon
       $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'features_one_icon',
        array(
            'default' => 'fa-fa box',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_key',
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'features_one_icon_control',
         array(
            'label' => __('Select Icon', 'text-domain'),
            'section' => 'features_block',
            'type' => 'select',
            'settings' => 'features_one_icon',
            'choices' => tar_icons() /*With function tar_icons() I'm pulling all the icons from the function */
        )
    );
```

**Code in `customizer.js` file**

```
wp.customize( 'features_one_icon', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( to ) {
            $( '.features-block-one .icon-one span' ).css( to  );
          } );
    } );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think You have error on default value for setting, You write
'default' => 'fa-fa box'

instead 'fa fa-box'.

I can't find box icon on fontAwesome too.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your answer. Yes, that was a typo even correcting that one didn't solve the problem.However with the help of a friend I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed "echo". Use the code below. Should work.

```
<span class="<?php echo get_theme_mod('features_one_icon' ,'fa fa-bullseye');?>">  </span>
```